# Omitting the word "As"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Below is a reply from a friend of mine ( not a native speaker, like me) to my question:-

"An acid, WEAK AS acetic acid can also be used."

If I were him, I would've said:-

"An acid  AS WEAK AS acetic acid can also be used."

Obviously, the word "As" is omitted in his reply. Again, I want to know, if it is grammatical and if so, what is the grammar behind this?

Comment: If you give us the full context it should be obvious whether ***as weak as acetic acid*** is defining or non-defining, which *could* affect the meaning. There's no meaning attached to whether or not to (sloppily, imho) omit the first of the matched pair of **as**'s, except you wouldn't see it omitted in formal writing.

Comment: My Q:- should I use a strong acid to completely neutralize lye? His Ans:- An acid, weak as acetic acid can also be used. I took it for granted that he meant An acid "as weak as" acetic acid can also be used ( = equally weak)

Comment: His phrasing is a bit "loose" - but that's not surprising, given it seems to be a fairly relaxed informal context. I assume that in a more formal context he might have written ***Any** acid - even one as weak as acetic acid - can be used* (the word ***also*** seems out of place, given the exact context). But the important thing is he omitted the first ***as*** from the "matched pair" idiomatic construction. Which has no significance apart from marking the text as relaxed informal.

Comment: ...the idea that explicitly including initial ***as*** identifies it as a "simile" (and *without*, it's a "metaphor", with some subtly different implications) is just nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, both forms are correct, grammatically speaking, but may have slight differences in their nuance of meaning.

*"An acid, WEAK AS acetic acid can also be used."*

(There should be a comma after "acetic acid," however.)  This form expresses that one can use an acid if it is no stronger than acetic acid.  It might imply a formulation of that acid such that, if it were too strong, it were diluted to make it weaker--such as vinegar which only has a small percentage of acetic acid.

*"An acid AS WEAK AS acetic acid can also be used."*

This is very nearly the same in meaning, but implies (to my mind, at least) that the acid itself, and not just its concentration, should not be stronger than the strength of acetic acid.  The "as weak as" is a simile, a comparison.  Instead of saying simply "like" (i.e. "similar), it might mean *equivalent*.  In this case, sulfuric acid would probably not be recommended, even if it were sourced from natural *desmarestia* which produces a weak concentration of it.  Perhaps ascorbic acid would be more equivalent in strength, given proportionate concentrations.

But the difference is too subtle, even for a native speaker, to make any qualitative or objective distinction or rule between the two forms.  In essence, it is up to one's particular manner of speaking. In the first form, however, commas seem appropriate, whereas in the second form they are unnecessary.

**What does "as" mean?**

The real essence of the difference boils down to the meaning of "as" in English.  It can mean "like" or it can mean "is."

For example:

*"His advice is as good as a doctor's."*  (One might infer that he is not a doctor, but gives good medical advice--like a doctor would.)

*"He speaks as a doctor."* (One might infer that he *is* a doctor.)

These inferences are not unquestionable and closed to interpretation--the meaning could go the other way; e.g. *"he speaks as a doctor"* might mean he speaks *like* a doctor, but is not himself a doctor.  Unfortunately, "as" in English can be ambiguous.  And it is because it can be used in two different ways that either sentence in the "acid" example might be seen as correct.

Comment: I don't agree. If you put a comma after initial ***An acid***, you need another matching one after ***acetic acid***. Which would imply you although you *can* also use (weak) acid, the default is that what you'd use isn't even "acid" at all (perhaps the default is PH-neutral, or even *alkali*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure I understand fully what you are getting at, but your comment caused me to see an ambiguity in my answer that I just fixed.  I meant to say that the phrase should be set apart by commas, i.e. that another comma is needed after "acetic acid" in the first example--which I just clarified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've cancelled my d/v following your edit. What I meant was if ***as weak as acetic acid*** (the presence / absence of the first ***as*** being syntactically and semantically irrelevant) is set off by commas, that makes it effectively ***parenthetical, optional***. In which case it's *slightly* more likely the "default" isn't even an acid at all (without the commas, or if the "parenthetical" is omitted altogether, the implication might be that the default is ***strong*** acid).

Comment: Anyway, I've just read a bit more of te answer, and downvoted *again*. It's not really true to say it's "correct" to omit the first ***as*** - that's just something characteristic of relaxed speech. ***Which has no effect on the meaning.*** We can in principle draw a *very* fine distinction between *[as] weak as acetic acid* being a ***defining*** or ***non-defining*** relative clause (based on commas / pauses), but you don't seem to address that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Vote however you wish.  I have years of experience teaching English grammar to English-language learners; but put 10 grammarians in the same room and pose a question to them and one will likely receive at least five different answers.  English, unlike Spanish (in Spain), has no organized body to settle the standard for the language, and opinions often diverge.  We do not all see things in the same way.

Comment: You seem to be making a semantic distinction based on whether the first word of ***as [ADJ] as*** is omitted or not. All I can say is I completely reject that distinction. It's just a characteristic of relaxed informal spoken contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It is not a matter of formality at all.  It is a matter of usage.  If I say: "A single hair, weak as it was, uneventfully maintained the sword over Damocles' head," I mean that the hair was weak.  I am not comparing it to anything else.  If I were to say "as weak as a thread," I would be making a comparison, simile fashion.  While the usage with or without "as" makes very little difference, there is still a subtle distinction in nuance between them.

Comment: Now I'm *really* struggling to follow your thinking! Why on earth would you think *weak as **it was*** somehow justifies discarding the first ***as***, but ***as weak as a cotton thread*** presumably *doesn't*? What about making a cup of tea *[as]* [*strong as you like*?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+strong+as+you+like%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Formal writing of a century ago would likely differ from today's standard on this question.  It may well be that my understanding of this question is influenced by my extensive exposure to English of the 17th-19th centuries.  They had a different understanding of English grammar than is more commonplace today, such as seldom, if ever, ending a sentence with a preposition.  Today we might say "Who did you give it to?"--and call it proper; they would have given low marks for such, preferring "To whom did you give it?"  As I consider this case, there are parallels with the "as."

Comment: Formal writing of *any* century wouldn't omit the first word from the "fixed" form ***as [adj] as***. And that business about not ending sentences with a preposition was a now-discredited conceit of some Victorian grammarians. It was never part of "real" English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is correct when applying to a comparison.  When a comparison is not intended or required, there is no need to form a simile.  I'm being warned against "extended discussions," so perhaps we should leave it here.